# mapping dataframe columns to a file

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to translate the names of my dataframe columns. So I have an excel file that has a bunch of values in the first column that also may be in the dataframe as columns and I want to map them to what they correspond in the file.

Here is what I am talking about:

```
#df
balance transactionid   date currcencid
xxx     xxxx            xxx  xx
xxx     xxxx            xxx  xx

#df1 (excel file read into a dataframe with index_col=0) # so colnames is the index of df!
colnames  Spanish   Polish
xxx       xxx       xxx
balance   saldo     xxx
xxx       xxx       xxx
date      fecha     xxx
```

I want to loop through my columns of df and take the Spanish equivalent of that value whether there is a match in the index.

This is what I am doing:

```
for col in df.columns:
    if col in df1.index:
        df.rename({col:df1.loc[col]['Spanish']})
```

So if this case my dataframe should like in the end

```
saldo  transactionid fecha  currencid
xxxx    xxxx          xxx    xx
xx      xxx           xxx    xx
```

I have also tried that operation without looping and I do not have any success. I would not mind an extensive explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, just do:

```
df = df.rename(columns=df1['Spanish'])
```

`rename` can take a Series as input.

Comment: @mowzway - so cool. that easy. but why my code is actually wrong, please?